# are code igniter conventions enforced?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp, naming-conventions, codeigniter-2

I am new to code igniter, coming from a solid **CakePHP** background. The user guide covers certain conventions to follow when naming controllers, models, views, and then classes + functions but are they actually enforced anywhere? You manually load both views and models, and controllers can be routed to. So is there any real reason to follow the conventions? I personally think they just make all my files and underlying code look pretty *fugly* and id rather just override them.

Comment: I'm quite interested in this topic myself, but as to my mind, if the project I'm working on myself won't be released to public or if the public(e.g. a team) agrees to me, I'm not obliged to follow conventions covered in CI guide. How can someone possibly like to use one framework or another if they cannot use it as they wish?

Comment: thats really why I switched to CodeIgniter, so I may have more freedom in my code and not everything is automagical (which I'm just more comfortable with). Though I don't see places in this where these conventions are forced, I just need to make sure before started a large project

Comment: What conventions exactly are you referencing? Only the controller/method naming or style conventions like placing `{` on the next line after functions, methods, conditionals and loops?

Comment: controller/model/function NAMING style conventions. it says they MUST be used but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I can't remember where they were obligatory, most likely nowhere. But if you are just starting, I want to warn you that model names and controller names, as well as library names must not match. I had a situation where my model and controller names were the same, like `users` and that caused errors, so from now on I name my controllers `c<name>`, it gets easier to see where is what in IDE tabs, but requires you to route to them if you care about SEO or pretty URL.

Comment: yes, I am planning to prefix all my models Cocoa style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CodeIgniter will never enforce anything on you, except for cases where it's a security or functional requirement.